# Remove 'US' before '$' in currency displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, currency-formatting

I'm using `.ToString("C")` method to show decimal number in currency format. But result looks lke ***"US$5,365.20"*** instead of ***"$5,365.20"***.  I've tried to use `.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"))`, results the same. But when I've tried to use another culture (en-GB, for example) then everything was ok (**£1,234.56**). 

So, why "US" is appeared before "$" symbol? And how can I remove it?

**UPD** I'm sorry. Just checked it again, and i see, that with `new CultureInfo("en-US"))` all works perfectly, i looked on another label :) But now i see(thanks to @Mike McCaughan), that current currency symbol is "US$". Current culture name is 'en-US'.

Comment: I've never seen that before, are you sure you're not appending `US` to your string? Post the offending code.

Comment: Can u share your code snippet? Seem to work as designed here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RSOHZE

Comment: To get an existing `CultureInfo`, I think you need to use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Nah you don't, `new CultureInfo("en-US")` is fine

Comment: Have you tried with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: @mattytommo Neat. Learned something new :). @Eugen, take a look at the output for `(new CultureInfo("en-US")).NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` and see if the US is in front of the `$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"US" appears before "$" because someone customized the currency symbol using the Region applet in Control Panel. To get the default currency symbol, use [`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky2chs3h(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
decimal amount = 5365.20M;
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C"));                                      // US$5,365.20
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US")));            // US$5,365.20
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))); // $5,365.20
```

The MSDN Library documentation explains the difference. For the constructor:

> The user might choose to override some of the values associated with the current culture of Windows through the regional and language options portion of Control Panel. ... If the culture identifier associated with *name* matches the culture identifier of the current Windows culture, this constructor creates a CultureInfo object that uses those overrides...

And for GetCultureInfo:

> If *name* is the name of the current culture, the returned CultureInfo object does not reflect any user overrides. This makes the method suitable for server applications or tools that do not have a real user account on the system and that need to load multiple cultures efficiently.

**UPDATE:** If `.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"))` works but `.ToString("C")` doesn't, then the problem could be that some other code assigned your thread a custom CultureInfo with "US$" as the currency symbol.

Comment: The thing is that `new CultureInfo("en-US")` works for me as i see, check my UPD. Then strange, according to you it should not work. But i think that overriding can be a reason, anyway.

Comment: Are you sure the other label in your UPD uses `.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"))`? Also note that this code will apply user overrides only if the Windows region is in fact "English (United States)".

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure. About windows settings. I used date, currency and other settings for my local region anyway (i've already checked it with US settings, the same). Culture settings set up by DotNetNuke CMS that are the basement for that web app. So now i think that problem is there.

Answer (score 3):

Testing what `Mike McCaughan` has provided I think that it will remove the `US` but it will also add `$$` to the existing Currency. I have tested this and this will work, but I think that there are some better ways of doing this but this will yield the following

Remove the `US` initially would solve this in one line..

```
var currency = "US$5,365.20".Replace("US", string.Empty);
```

or Alternative

Taking `B.K` suggestion you can take this even one more level from 3 lines to 2 lines

```
var currency = 5365.20M;
var finalCurrency = currency.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US")).Replace("US", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Why not just replace `US` with `String.Empty` in the first place, rather than having to jump through hoops with the dollar sign?

Comment: That's True as well.. I will edit the answer to show that alternative

Comment: @DJKRAZE, yeah, i can just replace it. But i used it in hundreds of places. I think the better idea is to change `CurrencySymbol` on app. start while i'm searching for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the currency symbol for that specific culture's shallow clone:

```
var d = 2353.23M;
var currencyFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.Clone();
currencyFormat.CurrencySymbol = "$"; // Change to something like %^# to test it
var currency = d.ToString("C", currencyFormat);
```